# Multiple contact forms with different email templates

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have multiple contact forms on my store, being inserted into CMS pages like this:

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

I would like to be able to set which template us used to format the email content. I have two emails created in System > Transactional Emails, how do I set two different forms to use two different email templates.

Answer (score 0):

Here is paid extension as require to set your custom template to your Custom block

[extended-contacts](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/extended-contacts.html)

It has very good features to use from back end to select your custom block as well as your email template with list of recipient to send email

hope it will help you.

Comment: It looks like you can only set a single email template, I would like to be able to have different transactional email template set per form.